# Incorrect syntax near something

Tags: sql, sql-server

I write a stored procedure which I pass a year as a parameter in that. I have `saledatestr` as a `varchar` column. I want to get select where 4 first digits of `saledatestr` be equal to my parameter here is my code:

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects 
           where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[spSaleCustomerYear]') 
             and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
    drop procedure [dbo].[spSaleCustomerYear]
GO

create procedure spSaleCustomerYear
    (@year varchar) 
with Encryption 
as 
    select
        c.CustomerCode,
        PLE.PLEName,
        s.SaleNo,
        s.FinalPrice,
        s.SaleDateStr
    from 
        SMS.tblsales s
    left join 
        SMS.tblCustomers c on c.CustomerID = s.CustomerRef
    left join 
        GNR.tblPrincipalLegalEntities PLE on PLE.PrincipalLegalEntityID = c.PrincipalLegalEntityRef
    where 
        s.CustomerRef not in (select CustomerRef 
                              from SMS.tblSales s1
                              --left join dbo.tblFiscalYear FY on FY.FiscalYearID = s1.FiscalYearID
                              where (LEFT(s1.SaleDateStr, 4) = @year)  
                                and SaleDocType = 4)
```

The error is on this line:

```
(LEFT(s1.SaleDateStr, 4) = @year)
```

Please help me guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which dbms do you use? Please add the tag for it

Comment: please add the complete error message

Comment: @Jens Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '4'.

Comment: Why are you dealing with this on string level? Why don't you pass in the year as `INT` and deal with the `s1.SaleDateStr` as a real *`date` (or `datetime`) typed value* using the function `YEAR()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

You should ***NEVER EVER*** define a parameter like this:

```
create procedure spSaleCustomerYear
    (@year varchar)
```

This defines a varchar parameter of ***exactly ONE character length*** which is typically *not* what you want.

You should ***ALWAYS*** (no exceptions!) define an **explicit length** when using `varchar`! This also applies to defining SQL variables, or to define target types in `CAST` or `CONVERT` statements.

Change this parameter to:

```
(@year varchar(4))
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: @AliEshghi: what do the values in `s1.SaleDateStr` look like??

Comment: @ marc_s it is varchar (10) value= 'yyyy/mm/dd'

Answer (score 0):

In your procedure, can you replace the line

```
where (LEFT(s1.SaleDateStr, 4) = @year)
```

with this and try:

```
WHERE YEAR(CAST(s1.SaleDateStr AS DATETIME)) = CAST(@year AS INT)
```